# SwipeToDismiss works only on Buttons?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, swipe-gesture

I am Using [SwipeDismissTouchListener](https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA/tree/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss) in my Code but it seams to work only for buttons , not for TextView, RelativeLayout etc.

How to use it for other View Types?

Answer (score 2):

Got the Solution :)

It works for all views required they should have an onClickListener implemented. Buttons tend to have that by default :)