# Swipe to dismiss table row not working

Tags: android, tablerow

I'm trying to implement swipe to dismiss feature to my app, I have a TableLayout with a bunch of TableRows inside it, and each table row has a TextView and EditText, like this

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/textView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

And following [this](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss) I added the SwipeDismissTouchListener.java class to my app and added this to my Activity's code inside the onActivityCreated() method.

```
        tableRow.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(
                      tableRow,
                      null,
                        new SwipeDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(Object token) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {
                                tableLayout.removeView(tableRow);
                            }
                      }));
```

But nothing's happening when I swipe the tableRow, what seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement `onClickListener` for the view. Then only `SwipeDismissTouchListener` seems to work.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20897322/1777090). Rest of your code looks fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 tableRow.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDismissTouchListener(
                      tableRow,
                      null,
                        new SwipeDismissTouchListener.DismissCallbacks() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean canDismiss(Object token) {
                                return true;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onDismiss(View view, Object token) {
                                tableLayout.removeView(view);
                            }
                      }));
```